# Sorting multidimensional array by two different key or value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

This example depends on two keys/values instead of just one unlike many other examples I've seen in Stack-overflow. Apart from sorting array below by `primary` key, I also would like to sort it by `age` key so that I can achieve EXPECTED RESULT below. How should I modify CODE below to achieve it? CURRENT RESULT has `A-6-6` key misplaced because my code doesn't handle it yet.

**ORIGINAL ARRAY**

```
$myarray = [
    'Z-9-0' => [
        'primary' => true,
        'age' => 55
    ],
    'C-7-1' => [
        'primary' => false,
        'age' => 60
    ],
    'K-1-9' => [
        'primary' => true,
        'age' => 60
    ],
    'C-2-1' => [
        'primary' => false,
        'age' => 40
    ],
    'F-6-6' => [
        'primary' => true,
        'age' => 60
    ],
    'A-6-6' => [
        'primary' => true,
        'age' => 30
    ]
];
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
(
    [F-6-6] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 60
        )
    [K-1-9] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 60
        )
    [Z-9-0] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 55
        )
    [A-6-6] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 30
        )
    [C-7-1] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 
            [age] => 60
        )
    [C-2-1] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 
            [age] => 40
        )
)
```

**CODE**

```
uasort($myarray, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b['primary'], $a['primary']);
});

print_r($org);
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

As you can see, `A-6-6` is not in right place compared to expected result above. So the bigger the `age` the higher place it should appear.

```
(
    [A-6-6] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 30
        )
    [F-6-6] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 60
        )
    [K-1-9] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 60
        )
    [Z-9-0] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 1
            [age] => 55
        )
    [C-7-1] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 
            [age] => 60
        )
    [C-2-1] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 
            [age] => 40
        )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is matched to your question; however, you can have a quick glance of it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#114535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add an extra check for the 'age' key in the [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) when the values for the 'primary' key are equal'.

```
uasort($myarray, function($a, $b) {
    if ($b['primary'] === $a['primary']) {
        return $b['age'] > $a['age'];
    }
    return strcmp($b['primary'], $a['primary']);
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LVM5l)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.